# Alternatively presentation of the archive

Tags: wordpress

I'm searching for an alternativ view of the archiv output page.

So if you click on a archiv link you get a view e.g. of the Month.
And exactly this Page where i get the filtered output i want to apply some changes.

So i mean not:

```
wp_get_archives()
```

Best regards Illu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make a few small changes, then just filter it with the wordpress function [is_archive()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive), e.g.

```
<?php if (is_archive()) { ?>
Say hello to the archeologist users
<?php } ?>
```

...otherwise, if you want to have a completly different template for that page, then just create a file called archive.php in your theme directory. Hope I understood your question right :)

Some more resources for the is_archive() function is to be found [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates#Text_Displaying_Only_on_First_Page_of_Archive) - well explained examples. And some more information about template files are [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

Comment: Oh nice, that is exactly what i mean ;)